# How do I accesss gravatar?

Tags: avatar

In the administration under Your Profile, which is where I suspect it would be, I can't find anything relating to gravatar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place that gravatars are administered in WordPress core (without plugins, that is) is on the discussion settings page:

[image: Avatars]

If you want to access YOUR gravatar, go to http://gravatar.com and set up your profile. WordPress is set to automatically interface with gravatar using your user's email address to identify you with gravatar.com.